# How to upload xml file in karate with key value pair multipart form data?

Tags: xml, api, post, cucumber, karate

I am trying to automate an API, which has a POST method and which requires XML file as parameter and key. I am not able to do it. Can someone help me?

Sample code:

```
Feature: Sample API Test

  Scenario: POST API Test
    Given url 'some url'
    And multipart file file= {filename: 'somefile.xml', contentType:'application/xml'}
    And header content-type = 'multipart/form-data'
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Comment: read this carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#multipart-file if still stuck, edit your question with a working cURL command. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: thanks the first option worked for me posting it as an answer, what worked for me.https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#multipart-file

Answer (score 1):

@Peter, thanks for quick reply, I did update my code as per your suggestion and it worked.
So I gave the filename as the key and placed file in the same folder where I am writing the feature files.
    Feature: Sample API Test

```
  Scenario: POST API Test
    Given url 'some url'
    And multipart file "name of the key" = {read: 'somefile.xml', contentType:'application/xml'}
    And header content-type = 'multipart/form-data'
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

If there is any better way, please suggest. for now it worked.

Please find below screenshot of the successful execution.

[image: The output of tje script executed]

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. are you sure ? it is missing the `read` or the `value`

Comment: look - your answer does NOT have the `read` part but it is there in your screenshot. anyway, all the best for the future :P

Comment: @PeterThomas Hi I am trying to pass different variable to xml file, which is mentioned in above solution. Which I am reading as multipart file. Now the question is if I want to execute same test 50 times, by updating a variable in xml. how can we do it in karate? 
for example:
<users>
 <user>
   <name>#(name)</name>
 </user>
</users>

Now I want to pass 50 different names to the name variable and test should get executed 50 times, how can we do it? can you please guide me?

Comment: read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests